# Snipe-it with Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, https, dockerfile

I'm trying to host snipe-it image using docker following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyIIEVT5GYs&t=1308s

everything seem to work fine until I get to include my custom ssl Ceritficate to my snipe-it image, I have been trying for more than 3 Weeks but nothing works and i don't have any idea how to do that.

I would be very grateful for your help

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  snipeit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.alpine
    container_name: snipeit
    ports:
    - 8118:80
    volumes:
    - logs:/var/www/html/storage/logs
    depends_on:
    - snipedb
    - redis
    env_file:
    - .env.docker
    networks:
    - snipeit-backend

  snipedb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    volumes:
    - db:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
    - .env.docker
    networks:
    - snipeit-backend

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
    - snipeit-backend

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
    # - 1025:1025
    - 8025:8025
    networks:
    - snipeit-backend


volumes:
  db: {}
  logs: {}
networks:
  snipeit-backend: {}
```

my_env_file

```
# --------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED: DB SETUP
# --------------------------------------------
MYSQL_DATABASE=snipeit
MYSQL_USER=snipeit
MYSQL_PASSWORD=changeme1234
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=changeme1234
# --------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED: BASIC APP SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
APP_ENV=production 
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=MY_APP_KEY
APP_URL=http://my_ip:8118
APP_TIMEZONE='Europe/Vienna'
APP_LOCALE=en
MAX_RESULTS=500

# --------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED: UPLOADED FILE STORAGE SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
PRIVATE_FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
PUBLIC_FILESYSTEM_DISK=local_public

# --------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED: DATABASE SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=snipedb
DB_DATABASE=snipeit
DB_USERNAME=snipeit
DB_PASSWORD=changeme1234
DB_PREFIX=null
DB_DUMP_PATH='/usr/bin'
DB_CHARSET=utf8mb4
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: SSL DATABASE SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
DB_SSL=false
DB_SSL_IS_PAAS=false
DB_SSL_KEY_PATH=null
DB_SSL_CERT_PATH=null
DB_SSL_CA_PATH=null
DB_SSL_CIPHER=null

# --------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED: OUTGOING MAIL SERVER SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDR=
MAIL_FROM_NAME='Snipe-IT'
MAIL_REPLYTO_ADDR=
MAIL_REPLYTO_NAME='Snipe-IT'
MAIL_AUTO_EMBED_METHOD='attachment'

# --------------------------------------------
# REQUIRED: IMAGE LIBRARY
# This should be gd or imagick
# --------------------------------------------
IMAGE_LIB=gd


# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: BACKUP SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
MAIL_BACKUP_NOTIFICATION_DRIVER=null
MAIL_BACKUP_NOTIFICATION_ADDRESS=null
BACKUP_ENV=true


# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: SESSION SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
SESSION_LIFETIME=12000
EXPIRE_ON_CLOSE=false
ENCRYPT=false
COOKIE_NAME=snipeit_session
COOKIE_DOMAIN=null
SECURE_COOKIES=false
API_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_YEARS=40

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: SECURITY HEADER SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
APP_TRUSTED_PROXIES=192.168.1.1,10.0.0.1
ALLOW_IFRAMING=false
REFERRER_POLICY=same-origin
ENABLE_CSP=false
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=null
ENABLE_HSTS=false

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: CACHE SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
CACHE_PREFIX=snipeit

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: REDIS SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: MEMCACHED SETTINGS
# --------------------------------------------
MEMCACHED_HOST=null
MEMCACHED_PORT=null

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: PUBLIC S3 Settings
# --------------------------------------------
PUBLIC_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=null
PUBLIC_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=null
PUBLIC_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=null
PUBLIC_AWS_BUCKET=null
PUBLIC_AWS_URL=null
PUBLIC_AWS_BUCKET_ROOT=null

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: PRIVATE S3 Settings
# --------------------------------------------
PRIVATE_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=null
PRIVATE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=null
PRIVATE_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=null
PRIVATE_AWS_BUCKET=null
PRIVATE_AWS_URL=null
PRIVATE_AWS_BUCKET_ROOT=null

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: LOGIN THROTTLING
# --------------------------------------------
LOGIN_MAX_ATTEMPTS=5
LOGIN_LOCKOUT_DURATION=60
RESET_PASSWORD_LINK_EXPIRES=900

# --------------------------------------------
# OPTIONAL: MISC
# --------------------------------------------
APP_LOG=stderr
APP_LOG_MAX_FILES=10
APP_LOCKED=false
APP_CIPHER=AES-256-CBC
GOOGLE_MAPS_API=
LDAP_MEM_LIM=500M
LDAP_TIME_LIM=600
```